# How to create more than one stored procedure using ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net

The situation is:

I want to create two stored procedures:

```
query1 = CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc1 AS SELECT * FROM TEST1;
```

and

```
query2 = CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc2 AS SELECT * FROM TEST2;
```

I can do it using

```
command.CommandText = query1;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.CommandTest = query2;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is it possible to create these two procedures in one ExecuteNonQuery(), like:

```
command.CommandText = query1 + query2;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Whats wrong? It doesn't fit into my curent architecutre and I don't want to rewrite it :). Higher layer gets query/command which creates "something" and simply creates it. I don't want to discuss the architecuture - maybe it is bad, but the question was "is it possible to do it in one query?"

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround, you can wrap each procedure with an EXEC statement

e.g.

```
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc1 AS SELECT * FROM TEST1;')
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc2 AS SELECT * FROM TEST2;')
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc3 AS SELECT ''hello'';')
```

Note: Make sure to replace each single quote `'` with two single quotes `''` within the procedure text (example in MyProc3)

Answer (score 1):

No, everything within a single call of ExecuteNonQuery is executed as a single batch. To quote from [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

> The CREATE PROCEDURE statement cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch.